# Mod Function in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, math, aggregate-functions

I have a variable in my stored procedure as

```
Declare @ptempAmount decimal(18, 0)
```

This variable is set using a function which returns a decimal value postive/negative.

Now the problem is when the function returns positive value it is acceptable but when it returns negative i want to convert it into positive.

```
@ptempAmount = 15 : Acceptable

@ptempAmount = -15 --> Function(@ptempAmount) --> +15
```

Is there any function in SQL Server for this problem?

Thanxx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ***ABS function***;

```
   SET @ptempAmount  = ABS(-15) --> returns 15
```